# how to get images for news feed app

Tags: ios, json, image-processing, feed

I'm developing a news feed app for ios, and I'm using [Feedzilla news API](http://code.google.com/p/feedzilla-api/wiki/RestApi). I have the news feed api correctly implemented, but Feedzilla only returns the news summary and other meta data, but not any images for the news article. So now I have to figure out a different way to get the news article images to display in my app. Does anyone know of either:

1. A different newsfeed service that will give news article images
2. A way to fetch news article images with feedzilla or
3. A way to fetch image thumbnails from a web page

Thanks.

Comment: Try this link to Iphone RSS Feeder: [IPhone RSS Feeder](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-rss-reader-application-with-source-code.php)

Comment: What did you do in the end? I'm planning on a similar idea

Comment: I ended up sticking with Feedzilla. I've not been able to find a similar news feed service. The iPhone RSS Feeder suggested in the comment above uses BBC RSS feed. But I'm not able to filter that feed based on search criteria, and my app requires search. Let me know if you find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting url of the article/news as metadata after parsing the feed?

`If yes.`

Now using this URL you can read whole content of the news page and using any DOM parser you can read image url as well.