# iOS apps with RSS feeds that can extract image

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss-reader

Is is possible for the app to add RSS feed and at the same time look into that link for some image to display on the table view? I have seen apps with just text display on the table view is it possible to add an image from that feed as a display?

Comment: I also want to display image in tableview in RSSFeed app.if you have solved the issue can you share? i am using rayWenderwich RSSFun for Feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [how to get images for news feed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532740/how-to-get-images-for-news-feed-app), chandhooguy advised checking out [iPhone RSS Reader Application](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-rss-reader-application-with-source-code.php). Looks like that grabs images on the detail screen. Strikes me that it wouldn't be hard to display on tableview, though I haven't gone through that code, so I can say.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Appreciate it